# CKEditor not working on MAC chrome and MAC Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, ckeditor

Using CKeditor on my mac (trying to edit an object), the CKEditor.js fails with this error:

```
"TypeError: undefined is not an object 
    (evaluating 'c[a].dir=c.rtl[a]?"rtl":"ltr"')
fckeditor.js:219
mckeditor.js:220:181
yckeditor.js:220:337
sckeditor.js:220:420
onerrorckeditor.js:221:362"
```

Any clue why this is happening, on other MAC (different locale) works perfectly, and on windows browsers also perfectly showing the tool bar for editing.

Thank yo in advance,
Willy.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the editor again.  I had similar problem and after long time I realized that some jsfiles were missing and other was without right permission.  After I unzipped it again everything started to work.  I know this is simple, I am not sure what happened when I unzipped it the first time but it took me some time to figure out that the unzip was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the language in settings and set basepath. I have the same problem and when i set language in config it started work.

Comment: How do you set the language?